# Can't see the headers set by Interceptors in request calls in devtools

Tags: angular, http, google-chrome-devtools, angular-http-interceptors

In my Angular 5 application, I'm using interceptors to set header. But when I see the HTTP request calls in devtools I can't see the header I set.

Interceptor Class:

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const duplicate = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer Lalinda`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(duplicate);
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

Capture of Devtools request :

[image]

Update:

app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    { provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG},
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
    AuthenticationService,
    LocalStorageService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorService, multi: true }
  ],
```

Comment: Are you import this service in app module?

Comment: @Shifenis Yes, I did. Please check the updated section.

Comment: @Shifenis Can I see the attached headers in Options call ? My option call is getting failed.

Comment: What does your options returns?

Comment: I'm getting 'Access to Origin is blocked'. I know the reason as well. in back-end, CORS are not enabled. But can't I see the additional headers in Option call ?

Comment: In the Options you **can't** see the Authorization Header

Answer (score 0):

try this way it worked for me:

const duplicate = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer Lalinda') });

Comment: Can't add 'Bearer Lalinda' without single quotes. Still can't see it in request calls in devtools.

Comment: add it with single quotes or as a variable thats what i meant

Comment: Still can't see

Comment: try a console log inside the interceptor and see if it works or not, the interceptor might be not being fired

Comment: console log works. Anyway can I see the attached headers in Options call ? My option call is getting failed.

Comment: I think that probably there is something that overwrite its value, check the login service call